# Missing values in daily return (quantmod)

Tags: r, quantmod

I would like to compute the returns of stocks with quantmod.
This is the function I use:

```
return<- function(x){
as.xts(dailyReturn(na.omit(getSymbols(x,auto.assign=FALSE, 
from="2015-03-10", to="2015-03-30"))))}
```

What I get with (same problem with other stocks and other time windows)

```
return("^GSPC")
```

- 2015-03-10____  -0.015403518
- 2015-03-11____  -0.001917680
- 2015-03-12____   0.012601440
- 2015-03-13____  -0.006074711
- 2015-03-16____   0.013533671 ## days 14 & 15  missing
- 2015-03-17____  -0.003320174
- 2015-03-18____   0.012158422
- 2015-03-19____  -0.004872579
- 2015-03-20____   0.009012755
- 2015-03-23____  -0.001745731 ## days 21 & 22 missing
- 2015-03-24____  -0.006139422
- 2015-03-25____  -0.014558906
- 2015-03-26____  -0.002377500
- 2015-03-27____   0.002368562 ## days 28 & 29 missing
- 2015-03-30____   0.012236645

I can't figure out what the problem is. I hope you can help me out!
Thank you!

Comment: Stock markets are closed on Saturdays and Sundays. I am assuming you have noticed that the gaps are consecutive and occur every 7 days

Comment: Well ... yes - thank you!